# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 31436096 bytes)

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.6

I'm new to Joomla and I'm now using Joomla 1.6

The problem I encounter is when I try to upload an extension via the admin tool and I get the following error message:

```
"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 31436096 bytes)
 in C:\AppServ\www\libraries\joomla\filesystem\file.php on line 295"
```

I've read some relevant messages but didn't get it solved. The `phpinfo` returns a value which I think may be relevant:

```
1)upload_max_filesize      local value=200; master value=200
```

Am I correct? If yes, how can I change it? (I can't remote to the server.)

Comment: If you are new to Joomla, I would recommend downloading Joomla 2.5.6. Version 1.6 was the core of the new release and is no longer supported.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be you're running out of the allowed memory size.

Try to optimize your code and query.

Also you can change the php ini settings.

Here is the one .htaccess solution

```
php_value memory_limit 1000M
php_value max_execution_time 6000000
```

I've added arbitrary values, just change based on your requirements. And put this .htaccess at your projects root folder such that this changes will only be applicable to your project folder...

Answer (score 2):

Your memory limit (24 Megabyte) is rather low for Joomla and especially for its updater. I recommend at least 32 Megabyte, better 64 Megabyte.

The how to change is it is dependent on your server environment. If you have access to your php.ini you should look for a line that contains `memory_limit` and set its value to 32M (or 64M or whatever value works for you)

In case you can't access the php.ini try setting it trough the .htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 1000M
```

If that also fails you should contact your hoster. Some have a web interface to allow changing this settings. Unfortunately others doesn't allow changing it at all. Your only chance is begging your hoster to change its server configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try...
    put top of the file
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');