# Fatal error in joomla

Tags: php, caching, memory, joomla

In my website, sometimes there's a Fatal error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6472822 bytes) in /home/xxx/public_html/libraries/joomla/cache/storage/file.php on line 142
```

Comment: Which version of joomla are you running? It would appear some versions have a problem with some cache types: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/joomlabugsquad/okHVR0OMn4g

Comment: What are you trying to view while you get this? Give us more info...

Comment: Try disable caching in Global Configuration...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to amount of memory you set in php.ini. Look at this question, i think it's the same: [Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 31436096 bytes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606282/fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-25165824-bytes-exhausted-tried-to-allocate)